# CDH 5.3.2 - Need to restart impala daemon from shell/script

Tags: shell, impala

I am using CDH 5.3.2 cluster and have a requirement to be able to start/stop impala daemons from a script. The command mentioned in Cloudera Docs

```
sudo service impala-server start
```

works fine on my CDH 5.10 local VM but on CDH 5.3.2 cluster I get an error "impala-server: unrecognized service". On checking in /etc/init.d I see that no such service is listed either (while its listed in 5.10 version)

Then i tried to restart the service directly from impala bin directory

```
cd /usr/bin
./impalad stop
```

However running into below error now:

```
E0918 11:55:27.815739 12046 JniFrontend.java:622] FileSystem is file:///
W0918 11:55:27.817589 12046 JniFrontend.java:534] Cannot detect CDH version. Skipping Hadoop configuration checks
E0918 11:55:27.817620 12046 impala-server.cc:210] Unsupported file system. Impala only supports DistributedFileSystem but the configured filesystem is: LocalFileSystem.fs.defaultFS(file:///) might be set incorrectly
E0918 11:55:27.817631 12046 impala-server.cc:212] Aborting Impala Server startup due to improper configuration
```

I checked core-site.xml on Cloudera Manager and fs.defaultFS is correctly set so not sure where its picking the value from. Any pointers on how to go further on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The init.d service packages to start Impala from the command line are meant to be used for CDH users who do **NOT** want to use Cloudera Manager.  The right way to start and stop Impala on a Cloudera Manager cluster is to use the CM API:

https://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v17/index.html

- [start cluster service API](https://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v17/path__clusters_-clusterName-_services_-serviceName-_commands_start.html)
- [stop cluster service API](https://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v17/path__clusters_-clusterName-_services_-serviceName-_commands_stop.html)
- [commands API](https://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v17/path__commands_-commandId-.html)

The [tutorial](https://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v17/tutorial.html) shows how to use the CM APIs but for your situation you probably need to do:

```
$ curl -X POST -u USER:PASSWORD \
'CM_URL//api/v1/clusters/CLUSTERNAME/services/IMPALA_SERVICE/commands/stop'
```

replacing USER, PASSWORD, CM_URL, CLUSTERNAME, IMPALA_SERVICE_NAME with the appropriate values.  The curl command will return a command ID.

Then poll this API with the command ID to see that the start/stop operation completed.

```
$ curl -u USER:PASSWORD 'CM_URL//api/v1/commands/COMMAND_ID'
```

However, if you still want to use the init.d service packages then you'll need to install the `impala-server` package.

Comment: Thanks @tk421. I tried using cm api as per your suggestion : curl -u <username>:<password> 'http://<cm hostname:port>/api/v1/clusters/<cluster name>/services/impala/commands/stop'. But the command doesn't return anything and neither impala service got stopped. Also i tried listing available services using curl -u <username>:<password> 'http://<cm hostname:port>/api/v1/clusters/<cluster name>/services/ and impala does list as one of the running services.

Comment: I guess the service name "impala" is not correct. Any other way I can find the correct name apart from one I already tried?

Comment: Doing curl -u <username>:<password> 'http://<cm hostname:port>/api/v1/clusters/<cluster name>/services' then looking at the "name" parameter associated with the "type": "IMPALA" should work.

Comment: Thanks @tk421 for your support. The issue was that i was doing a GET call instead of POST. This command worked fine curl -X POST -u <username>:<password> 'http://<cm hostname:port>/api/v1/clusters/<cluster name>/services/impala/commands/stop